# PHP change default iterator using foreach for an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

With an object like this:

```
class test {
var $propa = 'a';
var $propb = 'b';
var $propc = 'c';
var $propd = array(1,2,3,4);
}
```

How do I iterate with test::$propd using foreach WITHOUT direct reference? eq:

```
$t = new test;
foreach ($t as $k => $v){
echo 'propd['.$k.']='.$v.', ';
}
// propd[0]=1, propd[1]=2, propd[2]=3, ...
```

Is there some stuff involving implement ArrayAccess?
Thx!

Comment: try this : echo 'propd['.$k->$propd[$v].']='.$v.', ';

Comment: Use of `var` is a throwback to PHP4, you should be setting a [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) instead (`public`/`private`/`protected`)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating functionality, and setting your properties as private.

Example:

```
class Test {

   private $propertyA = 'a';
   private $propertyB = 'b';

   public function getProperties()
   {
        return [
           'propertyA' => $this->propertyA,
           'propertyB' => $this->propertyB
        ];
   }

}
```

However, if the property values are to change then do getters and setters for the properties.

With the above code you can do:

```
<?php

$test = new Test;
foreach ($test->getProperties() as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value;
}

?>
```

You can also limit what properties you want to output with this method.

Comment: Yep, I know, but the main point is if there is a way to omit the '->getProperties()' portion and make the foreach loops direct in an array property.

Comment: Try setting the properties you want to loop to public.  Then do a var_dump and see what you have available.

Comment: No problem with scope. I found a possible solution implementing IteratorAggregate: [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.iterations.php)